# Dell Poweredge SC1420 server - NOISE

Tags: dell-poweredge

Does anyone know if Dell Poweredge SC1420 server is very loud to put in a home closet?

Answer (score 4):

Pretty much all server class machines are to noisy for a home closet. Also a closet would have no airflow causing the closet to get pretty hot.

Comment: I agree.  However, the SC1420 is a tower server and won't be quite as loud as a rack mount server but probably still too loud for a home closet.

Comment: It will be a little quieter, but the heat problem still exists.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Can you suggest some good small scale (read cheap) server for home use?

Comment: I tried putting my Poweredge 2500 in a closet.  Got too hot and burned out one of the power supplies.  If you install A/C in your closet though, and can keep the temp stable, then do it.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to buy quieter fans, I did this for a HP ML110 tower. Just make sure to check the CFM of each fan.